# How to rename the column data to unique strings to add unique constraints on column using unix timestamp?

Tags: sql, unique

I have table structure like
User Table 
id | Name 
1  | John 
2  | Sam 
3  | John 
4  | Sam 
5  | John

Now i want to add unique key constraint on name column of the table and update these values by appending timestamp so my output should be like

id | Name 
1  | John 
2  | Sam 
3  | John1533051839
4  | Sam1533051840
5  | John1533051841

I am trying to do it using temporary table? Ho can i do it?
I am trying below solution

```
drop table if exists temp_user;
```

`create table temp_user(id int(20), name varchar(128));`

```
insert into temp_user
  select id, name
  from user
  group by user.name;


update user u
  inner join temp_user temp_u ON temp_u.id = u.id
  SET u.name = CONCAT(u.name, UNIX_TIMESTAMP());


drop table temp_user;
```

Comment: What database platform, and what is wrong with your solution?  You don't say if there is an error or something else.

Comment: I am working with MySQL and when i execute this, i end up in renaming all names with the same string.

Answer (score 0):

if I've understood what you want, you need to add timestamp to Name to make it unique. Maybe this is not answer exactly your question but I have an hint. For this purpose you should use a trigger instead of make an index or write a more complex query and the advantages are the following:

1. an index is hard to mantain so you should consider to use an index only if indexed attribute is involved in frequent queries or in where clauses that significantly reduce the cardinality of your table.
2. if you have to write a more complex query probably it won't be usable in other applications, let's say that you have a web application with a form, a user may want to insert his or her name and not the timestamp.

Obviously the trigger syntax depends on your dbms but to give an example to what you can do in Oracle:

```
 create or replace trigger updateName
 after insert on user_table

 declare
 number_of_user int;

 begin

 select count(*) into number_of_user
 where Name = :NEW.Name;

 if(number_of_user <> 0) then
    :NEW.Name = CONCAT(:NEW.Name, UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
 end if;
 end;
```